# Problems adding and retrieving text with newlines in SQLite Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

So I can add data to a data base just fine but when I try and add

test sentence

testing sentence two

to the data base then retrieve it I'm getting

test sentence testing sentence two

I'm adding the test data from a string with the enter already put in and there is no way in the code for me to ad \n into since I'm pulling data from a Textview into a string and saving to the database.

Comment: You can modify your string after getting or when you need to use it anywhere in your program., Do not worry If you not strict requirement for new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well actually you can try to add \n. read each character of the string and find the location of the RETURN character. then in new String copy contents before that character, then copy '\n' and then copy the rest of the content of the string.

here's the code:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    String s=ed.getText().toString();
    int index=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        if(s.charAt(i)==10){
            index=i;
        }
    }
    String temp=s.substring(0, index);
    temp=temp+'\n';
    temp=temp+s.substring(index+1, s.length());
    tv.setText(temp);
}
```

Comment: here the temp is the required string, which you can save in database.

Comment: Thanks for the help this one really stumped me.